# Gravity setting not working on a Samsung device

Tags: android, alignment, gravity

I have developed an application which displays Hebrew strings that are retrived from a server.
I've tested the application on my emulator and all of them have been aligned to right. I'm using

```
android:gravity="right"
```

for the `TextView`.

When I test my application on Samsung TG-i9000, in "ignure" the garvity and align the text to left.

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the parent Layout containing TextView has `layoutWidth="wrap_Content"`, if so, then change it to `"fill_Parent"`